# c# best way to declare a class-level value in base class and set it at derived classes

Tags: c#, object-oriented

I have a root class and I'd like to add an indicator to it (property, static field, readonly field, virtual method or something like that), that should give me the same string value for every instance of that class, I would rather prefer to get that value without instantiating that class. GetObjType() virtual method is my current implementation of it but I am thinking there may a better way of doing this. Can you think of a better way of doing this, like class level singleton fields or something like that.

```
public abstract class CoreEntity
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public abstract string GetObjType();
}
public class DepartmanBase : CoreEntity
{
    public override string GetObjType() 
    {return "DEPARTMAN";}
    public string DepartmanName { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
    //Obj Type should be set as "DEPARTMAN" here and should be same in both derived classes
}
public class Departman : DepartmanBase
{
}
public class DepartmanView : DepartmanBase
{
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
}

public class Personnel : CoreEntity
{
    public override string GetObjType() {return "PERSONEL";}
    public string PersonnelName { get; set; }
}

public class Repository<T>
    where T : CoreEntity , new()
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        string objType = new T().GetObjType();
        Console.WriteLine("Object Type for: " + typeof(T).Name  + " is " + objType);
    }
}

void Main()
{
    var d = new Repository<Departman>();
    var dv = new Repository<DepartmanView>();
    var p = new Repository<Personnel>();

    d.DoSomething();
    dv.DoSomething();
    p.DoSomething();
}
```

Comment: Your title should sum up what you are trying to accomplish with your code, and not how you think it could possibly be done... That said, welcome to CodeReview ;)

Comment: We only comment on fully working code, we don't look at pseudo code.

Comment: @d347hm4n fixed the code, and added a sample, it works fine now.

Comment: Your code seems to be trying reinvent the wheel.  `Reflection` which has been part of the language for some time.  [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2362580/discovering-derived-types-using-reflection) might be a good starting point.

Comment: @JamesSnell It has nothing to do with Reflection, unless you are recommending using an Attribute.

Comment: @hazimdikenli Your code says otherwise - especially the `GetObjType` function...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What I've guessed from your code (and I might be wrong) is that you need to get some string from a type used in a persistence layer. The string might be a table name, or a value for a certain column. I've decided to call this a discriminator. Multiple types can have the same discriminator but each type can only have one.

I think it makes sense to introduce an inheritable attribute here, let's do that:

```
[AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Class, Inherited = true, AllowMultiple = false)]
sealed class DiscriminatorAttribute : Attribute
{
    readonly string discriminator;

    public DiscriminatorAttribute(string discriminator) 
   { 
        this.discriminator = discriminator;
   }

    public string Discriminator
    {
        get { return discriminator; }
    }
}
```

We'll also add a class which takes a type and gets us our string (if we have one).

```
public static class DiscriminatorService
{
    public static string LookupDiscriminatorForType(Type t)
    {
        var result = (from a in t.GetCustomAttributes(true)
                 where a is DiscriminatorAttribute
                 select a).SingleOrDefault() as DiscriminatorAttribute;
        return result != null ? result.Discriminator : null;
    }
}
```

This will allow you to change your repository to the following:

```
public class Repository<T> where T : CoreEntity
{
    public void DoSomething()
    {
        var objType = DiscriminatorService.LookupDiscriminatorForType(typeof(T));
        Console.WriteLine("Object Type for: " + typeof(T).Name  + " is " + objType);
    }
}
```

Some important things to note:

- You no longer need to create an instance to get the string
- you can remove the `new()` generic constraint

Obviously you need to decorate your classes with the new attribute:

```
[Discriminator("DEPARTMAN")]
public class DepartmanBase : CoreEntity
{
    public string DepartmanName { get; set; }
    public int ManagerId { get; set; }
}
public class Departman : DepartmanBase
{
    // Inherits discriminator from DepartmanBase
}

public class DepartmanView : DepartmanBase
{
    // Inherits discriminator from DepartmanBase
    public string ManagerName { get; set; }
}

[Discriminator("PERSONEL")]
public class Personnel : CoreEntity
{
    public string PersonnelName { get; set; }
}
```

Here's the full code in [.Net Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/RW3Zqf)

Comment: Looks pretty good. First of all, what do you think about the performance cost of this, should I consider caching it?

Comment: Time it and see :) I sometimes cache results from reflection but only when it's either in perf critical code or it's an extremely common operation. Interesting related Q here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1612122/to-cache-or-not-to-cache-getcustomattributes

Answer (score 1):

> I have a root class and I'd like to add an indicator to it (property,
>   static field, readonly field, virtual method or something like that),
>   that should give me the same string value for every instance of that
>   class, I would rather prefer to get that value without instantiating
>   that class.

This sounds like a very complicated way of saying you need a string constant which will return the same value from every instance of every class derived from DepartmanBase (sic)?

In which case all you need is:

```
public abstract class DepartmanBase 
{
    public const string Definition = "DEPARTMAN"; // Here is your member for static access
}
```

LinqPad test:

```
void Main()
{
    DepartmanBase.Definition.Dump();
    DepartmanView.Definition.Dump();
    Departman.Definition.Dump();
}
```

Output:

```
DEPARTMAN
DEPARTMAN
DEPARTMAN
```

If you are going to need to alter this string in child classes and/or you need a non-static implementation then something like:

```
public abstract class DepartmanBase 
{
    public const string Definition = "DEPARTMAN";

    public virtual string MagicString { get { return Definition; } }
}

public class Departman : DepartmanBase { }

public class DepartmanView : DepartmanBase { }

public class DepartmanWithDifferentDefinition  : DepartmanBase 
{
    public new const string Definition = "DEPARTMAN2"; // Your "static" member

    public override sealed string MagicString { get { return Definition; } } // Your instance member
}
```

LinqPad test:

```
Departman.Definition.Dump();
DepartmanWithDifferentDefinition.Definition.Dump();
new Departman().MagicString.Dump();
new DepartmanWithDifferentDefinition().MagicString.Dump();
```

Output:

```
DEPARTMAN
DEPARTMAN2
DEPARTMAN
DEPARTMAN2
```